# how do I search for specific text within a large group of documents?

Tags: html, wordpress, cyberduck

A coder worked on our site and likely wrote some javscript that includes the variable "source_id" -- I'm trying to find where that code lives on our wordpress install / server. We are on wpengine.

I remember being able to search WITHIN a large group of documents for specific text. I think from Cyberduck but now I can't find this feature.

How can I search many documents at once for specific text references?

Comment: specifically i remember a feature tool where you could just "find in", and have it search all the docs

Answer (score 2):

You can make a dump of your installation or connect via Cyberduck the server and search the specific variable in a complete folder with almost any text editor.

In [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) you can open a folder and search in files ( Find > Find in files ) the specific variable.

Comment: @user737408 : If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.